# Checking if browser is javascript enabled or not

Tags: javascript, browser

```
<noscript>
    <div>
        You must enable javascript to continue.
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Ok this makes sense, but still, the contents after this element will be shown, of course in a bad way, but what I am looking for is this:

If javascript is NOT enabled, I want to show this alert message, and NOTHING ELSE, I don't want to give advice "It's better if you enabled Javascript", I want to FORCE, "You MUST ENABLED so you can Continue!", I don't wanna give access to my website if javascript is not enbaled, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `No-Javascript` CSS class that hides everything else using CSS, and use Javascript to remove the class immediately (using an inline `<script>` block in that element).

Answer (score 4):

```
<noscript>
    <div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#f55;z-index=1000">
        You must enable javascript to continue.
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Also, your question wanted to throw an alert.. Which is JavaScript. You basically asked "how can I execute JS when JS is disabled?". But this HTML alone will do the trick.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  The other solutions to hide then show the body on page load would create the appearance of the page loading slower than it actually did.

Comment: I tried this but I customized it on my own, white background, I added more DIVs to make a blue box in the middle with rounded corners ( radius - only CSS ) and an alert message inside, damns this is sexy :D thanks bro.